# Python Openpyxl library cannot deal with automatic row height

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I'm currently using Openpyxl in a Django project to create an excel report.
I'm starting from a blank excel model in which column C has text wrap enabled.
Infact when I open the model and populate manually a cell I correctly get this

[image]

But when I run this trial code

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileExcel)
sh = wb["Rapportini"]
sh["C3"]="very very very very very very very very very very long row"
wb.save(fileExcel)
```

this is the result

[image]

I know openpyxl (strangely) cannot set row autoheight. I also tried to set wrap_text = True in the cell, but no way... any ideas ?

Comment: Auto height/width is a function of Excel. Openpyxl does not use Excel

Comment: Libreoffice itself has an auto height feature, just double click row lower boundary. It's Openpyxl that is not implementing it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem described is covered in the library's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`openpyxl.styles.Alignment`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html#openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment.wrapText) *module*, you can wrap text in a specific cell (i.e `C3`).

Try this :

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileExcel)
sh = wb["Rapportini"]
sh["C3"].value = "very very very very very very very very very very long row"
sh["C3"].alignment = openpyxl.styles.Alignment(wrap_text=True)
sh.column_dimensions["C"].width = 20
wb.save(fileExcel)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm using Openpyxl 3.0.5, which version are you using ?

Comment: It means that you failed to describe your problem _and/or_ your inputs because my code works actually. I'm using `3.0.10` btw.

Comment: I upgraded to 3.0.10 and tried it again, your exact code starting from a blank fresh-saved file and it's not working.
I forgot to say that I'm opening the file with LibreOffice and maybe that's the problem. I'll try to open it with MS Excel